# How to include javascript function in django html file

Tags: javascript, html, django

I want to create a Partially collapsing static sidebar
 following https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar within django project but the click to collapse sidebar doesn't work.

I tried putting the script in /static/JaS.js but seem like I don't know how to do this correctly

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app1/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app1/JaS.js' %}">

</head>
<body>


    <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- Sidebar  -->
            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div class="sidebar-header">
                    <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
                    <strong>BS</strong>
                </div>

                <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                            Home
                        </a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-briefcase"></i>
                            About
                        </a>
                        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">
                            <i class="fas fa-copy"></i>
                            Pages
                        </a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-image"></i>
                            Portfolio
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
                            FAQ
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                            Contact
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <!-- Page Content  -->
            <div id="content">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <div class="container-fluid">

                        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                            <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                            <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-dark d-inline-block d-lg-none ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <i class="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
                        </button>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <div class='container'>
                        {% block content %} {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
                });
            });
    </script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine except the Toggle Sidebar button. How to get this thing work or there is a better way?

Comment: Any console "f12" errors in browser?

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev Sorry, while I try to fix this my self I delete entire of project. and when I try to recover everything (forget to backup) to answer your question, it is not the same as I post this question.

Comment: @VitaliyTerziev I somehow recover everything back and tried again but this time the button is somehow working!